# Android Emulator UI broken

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I run Android Emulator

PC: MacbookPro Mid 2015

OS: Windows 10 Home

Android Studio 3.1.3

I tried to create many AVDs but the results were the same.
also tried to change the Windows display resolution, but no help.

[image]

Do I miss any configuration?

Update.

I can correct the UI by choosing Software Rendering

[image]

But it is very slow.

Comment: Freaky. I recommend [submitting a bug report](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs). In the meantime maybe just try a fresh reinstall of Android Studio (if you haven't already tried that)?

Comment: thank @Bryan, fresh install of Android Studio would be painful but i will try to see if it helps. Graphics Software is so bad, I can't run Appium for testing the Android Calculator app built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue is because of Driver for GPU

Corrected driver for **Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200**

The issue gone.